# Undefined reference to ClassName::ClassName

Tags: c++, class, undefined-reference

I'm using Code::Blocks to build my project, which contains three files: `main.cpp`, `TimeSeries.cpp`, `TimeSeries.h`. `TimeSeries.h` provides declarations for the `TimeSeries` class as follows:

```
template<class XType, class YType> class TimeSeries {
public:
    TimeSeries(void);
    ~TimeSeries(void);
};
```

Then `TimeSeries.cpp` contains:
    #include "TimeSeries.h"

```
template<class XType, class YType>
TimeSeries<XType, YType>::TimeSeries(void) {
}

template<class XType, class YType>
TimeSeries<XType, YType>::~TimeSeries(void) {
}
```

And finally, `main.cpp` contains

```
#include "TimeSeries.h"
typedef TimeSeries<float, float> FTimeSeries;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FTimeSeries input_data;
    return 0;
}
```

When building with C::B, I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `TimeSeries<float, float>::TimeSeries()'
```

What can I do?

Thanks,
CFP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for splitting code into header- and source-files is so that the declaration and the implementation are separated. The compiler can translate the source-file (compilation unit) into an object file, and other compilation-units that want to use the classes and functions just include the header-file, and link the object file. This way, the code has to be compiled only once, and can be reused by linking it.

The problem with templates is that, as long as there are no parameters provided for them, the compiler cannot compile them. The same template instantiated with different parameters results in different types. `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<float>` are, from the compilers perspective, not related in any way. Because of this, template-classes usually have to reside completely in a header-file, because, when the template is used, the compiler needs the complete definition in order to generate the class depending on the parameters.

As @Gabriel Schreiber pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744852/undefined-reference-to-classnameclassname/3745415#3745415), you can tell the compiler that he should compile the template with a specific set of parameters, making that available to other compilation units just by linking. However, this does not make the template available for other parameter sets.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 3):

Basically all templated code should be defined in a header, otherwise it will not be built since nothing uses it in the compiled unit.

Each cpp file is compiled as a separate unit, and thus constructor and destructor are not compiled. The compiler has no way of knowing what type of template argument you will use in main.cpp when it compiles TimeSeries.cpp.

Comment: So I'd put all the code in the header file? SOunds strange, doesn't it?

Comment: @CFP: May sound strange but for templates, that’s (unfortunately) the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this in your .cpp-file (below the definitions):

```
template class TimeSeries<float, float>;
```

When the compiler compiles TimeSeries.cpp it doesn't know which for which types the template is need because it is used in another source file. You need to tell the compiler explicitly.

Read about Explicit Template Instantiation in your copy of the Stroustrup or on the internet.

Comment: I see, thanks =) But that kills most of the power of templates, doesn't it?